# D3.js code not working for Creating circles based on data

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

i was trying to draw multiple circles based on data the code does not work. written this code by watching a tutorial the same code works for the instructor. i am using same d3 version as the instructor. also i cant draw any other shapes while circles variable code is in the file.

```
var data = [19, 15, 25, 85, 69];

var canvas = d3.select("#chart-area").append("svg")
 .attr("width", 400)
 .attr("height", 400);

var circles = canvas.selectAll("circle")
 .data("data");

 circles.enter()
 .append("circle")
 .attr("cx", function (d, i) {
    return (i * 50) + 25;
    })
 .attr("cy", 100)
 .attr("r", function (d, i) {
    return d * 5;
    })
 .attr("fill", #000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you're passing data as a string `"data"` and not your actual array of values.

Than you're doing `.attr("r", function (d, i) { return d * 5; })` which will multiply each value in array by 5 and thats gonna cause radius of each circle to be so huge that it will fill the whole svg container.

And lastly there's an issue with color value not passed as string - `.attr("fill", #000)`;

Here's [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lhqo2aw/).